# Do attention models change the sequences attended to for every novel sentence? Or do they have a general idea of where to look?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, attention

I've learned about many different types of attention models. But the one thing that I never understood was how they knew where to focus on/attend to in the sentence.

What I'm wondering is if they can pick out the necessary information even for a novel sentence (that is, something not from the training set). Or if they simply learn to focus on general parts of a sentence, which may or may not correspond to the words that need to be attended to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attention in NLP is determined by two key components:

1. the token ID (unique identifier for each word or subword-unit)
2. the position of the token in the document

Each of (1) and (2) is represented by a unique vector for each token & position, which are added together to get an embedding for token T at position P in a document.

There may be multiple types of embedding vectors for token T at position P. One of these will be used by the attention operator, which compares the similarity of this vector against the corresponding vector for another token T' at position P' (eg. dot product similarity). These scalar similarity scores are computed for every alternate token/position in the document (more specifically the attention context window) T' & P' and then renormalized to sum to 1. This produces what we refer to as the "attention weights" which people think of as what the model is "focused on" when computing a particular representation/prediction.

What is learned by the model is the embedding vectors themselves (via backpropagation). The embedding vectors fully determine what attention will later focus on, so the model is not directly learning what to look at per-say, but rather learning how to represent words/positions in a way that computing simple similarity between these representations leads to useful weights that can emphasize a particular part of the input (and what gets emphasized differs between different documents based on the words that occur at different locations).

Comment: So, would this mean that the model could still pick the right position (or set of positions) to attend to in the sentence, even if those positions were not encountered in the training sets? And the model is able to do this because it uses the input token's embeddings to match the token to the other tokens' embeddings (in the sentence)?

Comment: Yes it is possible for a model to attend to a novel position in a sentence (although not necessarily likely due to lack of extrapolation abilities in most neural networks). 

The position is typically embedded in sinusoidal fashion (check out "positional encodings"), so it is not necessarily the case that the embedding of the new position contains greater values than encountered in the embeddings of positions from training set.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation! I do have more questions (I realized my previous question wasn't worded well), so thanks for being patient! Since the model learns the embedding vectors, would this mean that the embeddings' values (of the word to be attended to) are learned so that they maximize the similarity score when multiplied by the input? And this would be able to account for novel positions because the model picks embedding values that maximize the score rather than memorizing what positions to focus on?

Comment: Yes basically, remember everything in backpropagation is jointly optimized to reduce the loss function (which is typically applied to model predictions). The embedding vectors are simply learned in a way that, when subsequently used to determine attention-patterns used to compute predictions, leads to the most accurate predictions. The model and training-update-process is never explicitly thinking about where it should attend, this is all totally defined by the embeddings and then embeddings are just learned to optimize the resulting prediction loss.